# Media Queries in Email [Gmail]?

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, gmail, media-queries

I'm just trying to send a little Christmas e-message around my friends/family, I've built it to be fully responsive etc the way I always do. However as it's just for friends I'm not going to send it via MailChimp which usually sends everything for me no problem.

The way I'm trying to send it is by opening the index.html file, selecting all, copying, then pasting into Gmail. This has always worked fine for me in the past, and does *work*. However this is my first responsive email that I'm trying to send this way, and it seems the media queries don't get brought across this way, at least not in the gmail -> hotmail test that I just did (Resizing window etc does nothing, just shows the desktop version).

Is there a better way of sending an already built HTML email, rather than just copying/pasting in Gmail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Gmail does not support the `<style>` tag. Media queries can only be called in the `<style>` tag, and not inline, therefore Gmail doesn't support them.

Here is the [support chart](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/).

I would suggest you stick to an ESP like Mailchimp for sending html email. But while you are playing around in Gmail, [here is a tool](https://litmus.com/scope/) that may help you debug issues with your email code.

Comment: This answer may or may not have been correct at the time it was written, but today it's not correct. It's still true, however, for the Gmail app on mobile devices.

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer is not actually correct! Gmail strips IDs and classes from the email body itself, but the style tag IS retained.

You can use the following:

```
*[summary~='fakeclassname'] {
    styles: here;
}
```

"Summary" is one of the attributes that Gmail does **not** strip out. After it occurred to me what Gmail was actually doing to emails I found this article that breaks it down in detail:

http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-emails-in-gmail-using-css-attribute-selectors/

There are helpful links on that page that get deeper into Gmail-specific targeting.

Note: the Gmail **app** does strip the style tag, and with a rising market share (Android no longer has a native app and pushes people to use the Gmail app) should be considered a starting point for mobile-first email development.